# Getting Single Users Info From Linkedin API

Tags: php, api, oauth, linkedin-api

Okay i've been fighting this system for about 3 days now and googling left and right and getting nothing close to what i want. That being said it though i would rely on the infinite wisdom that is StackOverflow..... So here goes.....

What I'm attempting to do is make an updated resume site for myself but as I'm to lazy to update it regularly i had the bright idea to make it auto populate itself with info from my LinkedIn account. I've created the LinkedIn app gotten connected with their api and retreved the information successfully the issue is anyone that visits the site gets prompted to login and approve my app once they do i rebuilds my resume site with their info (hilarious i know).

So the big question how can i be authorized for my own application and then store that authorization and only use that to get the data regardless of who visits the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind i found the solution which is to store your auth token and secret that are returned and use those for all requests after.